# XAML Pop up execute twice on checkbox event

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

I am using Xlabs.Forms.Controls Checkbox. I have set `Checked = False` in xaml and on `CheckedChanged` event, it will pop up a confirmation to prompt user if they want it be checked.

On my PopUp Page, I have set click event for button `Yes` and `No`. The pop up will execute twice if the condition is not the same, meaning when I click on the checkbox, it will auto be checked, so when I click `No` in my pop up, it will execute twice before closing the pop up. Does anyone know why is this happening?

**xaml**

```
<controls:CheckBox x:Name="checkbox" DefaultText="standard" CheckedChanged="checkbox_CheckedChanged" Checked="False"/>
```

**main page**

```
private void checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, XLabs.EventArgs<bool> e)
    {
        PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new cbPopUp(this, checkbox));
    }
```

**pop up page**

```
 public partial class cbPopUp
{
    Mainpage mainpage;
    XLabs.Forms.Controls.CheckBox checkBox;
    public cbPopUp(MainPage mpage, XLabs.Forms.Controls.CheckBox cb)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainpage = mpage;
        checkBox = cb;
    }

    private async void btnYes_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       checkBox .Checked = true;


        await ClosePopup();

    }

    private async void btnNo_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox.Checked = false;

        await ClosePopup();
    }
    private async Task ClosePopup()
    {
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();

    }

}
```

Comment: why you're using third party library for checkbox ,when Xamarin Forms have own **CheckBox**.

Comment: @sandeepsingh hi, I used xamarin forms checkbox but also have the same error of popping up twice before closing

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggest to you use default IsChecked value which is always false with Xamarin.Forms.CheckBox

```
<CheckBox CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"/>
```

also open PopUpPage as following:

```
void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
   Task.Run(async () => await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new YourPopup()));            
}
```

I'm using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             x:Class="your-nameSpace.PopupView" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" 
             BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <animations:ScaleAnimation 
      PositionIn="Center" PositionOut="Center" ScaleIn="1.2"
      ScaleOut="0.8" DurationIn="400" DurationOut="300" EasingIn="SinOut"
      EasingOut="SinIn" HasBackgroundAnimation="True" />
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">      
        //your design here
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

```
 public partial class PopupView : PopupPage
    {
        public LogoutPopupView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // if you want to use binding
            //this.BindingContext = new PopupViewModel();
        }
        private async void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
        }

        protected override Task OnAppearingAnimationEndAsync()
        {
            return Content.FadeTo(1);
        }

        protected override Task OnDisappearingAnimationBeginAsync()
        {
            return Content.FadeTo(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, thank you for helping! if i use `await PopupNavigation.Instance,PopAsync()` , it doesn't close the pop up..

Comment: @Charis I suggested use  you a bool variable and when popup page open then makes it true, because of value changing event is fire again. If the value of this bool is  already true, then fire an empty event on chechedChanged.